I want to check if cookies are stored on the site
I'm trying to steam the registration site to then store the data in a cookie and make submissions automatically
from seleniumbase import SB
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

with SB(uc=True) as sb:
sb.driver.uc_open_with_reconnect(
"https://visa.vfsglobal.com/egy/en/hrv/login",
reconnect_time=8
)

    WebDriverWait(sb.driver, 10).until(
        EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe"))
    )
    
    
    sb.type("input[formcontrolname='username']", "")
    sb.type("input[formcontrolname='password']", "")
    
    
    sb.click("button.mat-focus-indicator.btn.mat-btn-lg.btn-block.btn-brand-orange")
    
    cookies = sb.driver.get_cookies()
    for cookie in cookies:
        print(cookie)
    
    breakpoint()


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
